# SEO URL Behind Login That May/May Not Require Payment Structure

Tags: seo, url, authentication, payments, site-structure

I have the following parent URL:

```
example.com/courses/course_name/
```

Currently, that parent URL can be accessed without a login.

When a user is logged in, and they try to access a video child URL, 2 things currently happen:

If a logged in user is a free member and tries to access a free video:

```
example.com/courses/course_name/video
```

They can access and watch the video.

If a logged in user is a free member and tries to access a paid video:

```
example.com/courses/course_name/video
```

They get the same URL but this time the video page displays an upgrade membership button instead of displaying the actual video.

Is this fine for SEO or is there a better way to do this and rank better?